# .htaccess cache control max age doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a problem setting the cache expire date on my website. This is the code I use in .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

The file types I mentioned should have an expire date of 2 hours, but after hard refresh I see that all these files have an expiration date of one week. As an example, I select the .css file in Chrome inspect page and I see this information:

> Accept-Ranges:bytes
>
> Cache-Control:max-age=8000, proxy-revalidate
>
> Connection:close
>
> Content-Encoding:gzip
>
> Content-Length:20229
>
> Content-Type:text/css
>
> Date:Wed, 26 Jul 2017 09:02:31 GMT
>
> ETag:"1c8c1-55513528cb363-gzip"
>
> Expires:Wed, 02 Aug 2017 09:02:31 GMT
>
> Last-Modified:Mon, 24 Jul 2017 17:12:41 GMT
>
> Server:Apache
>
> Vary:Accept-Encoding

The cache control max age is working, but why is the file's expire date only one week after? Is this some kind of server cache or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have AllowOveride enabled? Without it, Apache will not process .htaccess.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. Also as I understand the max-age is working, because I see that value in the file properties window, but somehow "Expires" field overrides the cache expire date.

Comment: Have you checked your *.conf files in the /etc/apache folder, and other .htaccess files higher up the directory hierarchy for possible overridden cache values?

Comment: There is no other .htaccess files. I don't know about the .conf files, have to check with the server provider, will do that soon. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that cache-control:max-age always overwrites the expires tag so everything is ok.